# How to cast to a Wrapper container?

Tags: c#, linq, oop, inheritance, casting

Here's the definition of `Pagina` and `Scheda` coming from a DLL:

```
public class Pagina : BrObject
{
    public const int Home = 1;

    public Pagina();

    public string Titolo { get; set; }
    public string IDStatoPubblicazione { get; set; }
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }
    public string DescBreve { get; set; }
    public Allegati Immagini { get; }

    ... many others properties
}

public class Scheda : BrObject
{
    public Scheda();

    public string Latitudine { get; set; }
    public string SottoTitolo { get; set; }
    public string Titolo { get; set; }
    public PeriodiValidita PeriodiValidita { get; }
    public Allegati Immagini { get; }
    public Allegati Documenti { get; }
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }

    ... many others properties
}
```

Now, I'd like to make a `wrapper` class, so I can cast them to mine, getting only "some common parameters" I need:

```
public class WrapperObject : BrObject
{
    public string Titolo { get; set; }
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }
    public Allegati Immagini { get; set; }

    public WrapperObject()
    {

    }
}
```

But when I try to do this:

```
IList<Pagina> ListatoPagine = GetPagine();
IList<WrapperObject> list = new List<WrapperObject>();

...

list = ListatoPagine.Cast<WrapperObject>().ToList();
```

it fails: *Unable to cast object of type 'BrLayer.Pagina' to type 'WrapperObject'.*

I'm a bit rusted with OOP and C#...

Comment: What is `BrObject`? Please provide its code as well.

Comment: Simple solution is to use a mapping library like AutoMapper or write the boilerplate code to map the properties you need one by one.

Comment: @DavidG: excatly what I'd like to avoid :)

Comment: There's no automatic way to do this. You need one or the other. Honestly, go get AutoMapper, it's great and super easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your current situation

```
public class Pagina : BrObject
public class Scheda : BrObject
public class WrapperObject : BrObject
```

`Pagina`, `Scheda` and `WrapperObject` are three classes that all derive from `BrObject`. You can consider them "siblings".

There is no relationship defined between these three siblings, **except** that they have the same base class. This means the following casts are allowed:

**Casting upwards**.
This can be done implicitly, and is always correct.

- `Pagina` to `BrObject`
- `Scheda` to `BrObject`
- `WrapperObject` to `BrObject`

**Casting downwards**.
This requires explicit casting, only works if the original object is from the derived class (e.g. `Pagina`) but was cast to its base class (`BrObject`). In essence, you can only cast down after you've already casted up (therefore reversing/undoing the cast).

- `BrObject` to `Pagina`
- `BrObject` to `Scheda`
- `BrObject` to `WrapperObject`

**There is no valid cast between `Pagina` and `WrapperObject`.** You cannot cast from one sibling to another sibling.
If you take a `Pagina` object, cast it to a `BrObject`, and then cast that to a `Scheda` object, the compiler will not complain. It trusts that you know what you are doing. When you write an explicit cast, you are basically overriding the compiler's innate sense to point out your logical flaws.
However, you will receive exceptions when you run this code, **because a `Pagina` is not a `Scheda` or vice versa**.

There is no valid way to cast **sideways** (between siblings). Even if you manage to fool the compiler, you will still run into exceptions at runtime.

---

These three properties are defined in `Pagina`, `Scheda`, and `WrapperObject` :

```
public string Titolo { get; set; }
public string Descrizione { get; set; }
public Allegati Immagini { get; set; }
```

They have the same name (and type) everywhere. However, this is **coincidental**. There is no relationship defined between these fields, they just happen to be called the same.

*As a simple example, consider `myCountry.Name` and `myUser.Name`. These are two separate name properties that have nothing to do with eachother.*

### My suggested solution

I suspect you need the following OOP approach:

- `WrapperObject` derives from `BrObject`
- `Pagina` and `Scheda` both derive from `WrapperObject`

In this corrected version, you can always implicitly cast any `Pagina` object to a `WrapperObject`. The same applies for `Scheda`.
Please do note that there is still no valid cast from `Pagina` to `Scheda` (or vice versa), but your question does not show a need for this.

To implement this:

1. Correct the inheritance:

   ```
   public class Pagina : WrapperObject 
   public class Scheda : WrapperObject 
   public class WrapperObject : BrObject
   ```
2. Keep the three properties in `WrapperObject`, but **remove** the same properties from `Pagina` and `Scheda`.
3. Your casting should now work as intended (in your example):

   ```
   myWrapperObjectList = myPaginaList.Cast<WrapperObject>().ToList();
   ```

This is now a valid cast, **because `Pagina` inherits from `WrapperObject`**.

---

**edit**

My colleague informed me that I had confused "up" and "down" when talking about casting. This has sparked quite the debate in our team, not everyone sees it the same way.
It's possible that my way is different from how the majority on SO sees it.

However, it's not really relevant to the problem you're faced with. "up" and "down" are abstract concepts, you can use whichever you prefer.

I'm keeping my version in here, so that I remain consistent if I'm writing future comments.

Answer (score 2):

You do not provide any information to the program on how to transform one instance of `Pagina` into your wrapper-class.

This can be achieved e.g. by this:

```
list = ListatoPagine.Select(x => new WrapperObject { 
    Titolo  = x.Titolo,
    Descrizione  = x.Descrizione,
    Immagini  = x.Immagini
}).ToList();
```

Another way is to introduce a copy-constructor into your wrapping-class:

```
public class WrapperObject : BrObject
{
    public string Titolo { get; set; }
    public string Descrizione { get; set; }
    public Allegati Immagini { get; set; }

    public WrapperObject(BrObject o)
    {
        this.Titolo  = o.Titolo;
        this.Descrizione = o.Descrizione;
        this.Immagini = o.Immagini;
    }
}
```

Which can then be called like this:

```
list = ListatoPagine.Select(x => new WrapperClass(x)).ToList();
```

EDIT: As the properties don´t exist on the base-class you need two copy-constructors, one for every deriving type:

```
public WrapperObject(Pagina o)
{
    this.Titolo  = o.Titolo;
    this.Descrizione = o.Descrizione;
    this.Immagini = o.Immagini;
}
```

And for the other class accordingly. Anyway you´d better be off defining an interface which all your classes implement and that defines all the common-properties. This way you could create a new instance of `WrapperClass` based on an existiong instance *implementing that common interface*.

Comment: Isn't this "implicit" on casting? What's the purpose of inherit so? I can just made whatever object I need.

Comment: No, because your wrapper-class could have also members that aren´t defined in any of the other two ones. In this case you won´t provide any information on how to transform those. This is why C# doesn´t *implicitely* let you create objects based on another one deriving from the same base-class.

Comment: Actually this won't work because it assumes the relevant properties are part of the `BrObject` contract but, as seen in the code above, they are part of the derived classes. You could make the parameter `dynamic` or use reflection, but it's still a bit hacky.

Comment: @markzzz You didn´t mention that in your question, however I´ve edited my answer appropriately.

Comment: @HimBromBeere The code provided is pretty explicit about where the properties come from

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance works one way.

Let's say you have a class `Tree`, then a class `Oak` inheriting from `Tree`.

You can cast a `List<Oak>` into a `List<Tree>`, because all `Oak`s are `Tree`s.

But you cannot can a `List<Tree>` into a `List<Oak>`, because not all `Tree`s are `Oak`s.

You are facing the exact same problem here.

@HimBromBeere [provides a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45585803/5897829) for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A `WrapperObject` is neither a `Pagina` or a `Scheda`, so you cant cast it to one. It is their sibling (at the same level).

Sounds to me like you don't need the `WrapperObject`, but a collection of `BrObject` (the parent) - assuming `BrObject` is correctly designed with the right "shared" properties.

Comment: Yes. But `BrObject` doesn't contains `Titolo`, `Descrizione` and so on...

Comment: @markzzz Then it gets completely unclear how you want to turn a `BrObject` into a `WrapperClass`.